# Can I have cross database or cross server references through a relative path?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, migration

I have two databases, *db1* and *db2*, running on two different servers, *server1* and *server2*, and *db2* has some stored procedures that will modify the table columns on *db1*.

In these stored procs, we use Linked Servers and fully qualified names to refer to the tables on *db1*, like `[server1].[database].[dbo].[table1]`.

Now, we decided to migrate *db1* from *server1* to *server2*. After migration, *db1* and *db2* will both run on *server2*.

**Questions**

- Do I have to modify each single cross server reference to remove the `[server1]` name in the stored procs?
- Could we define cross DB or cross server reference through relative path, so we don't need to modify them every time the two databases change server?

Thank you.

Comment: After `db1` migrates over, do you have _any_ other need for `Server 2` to connect to `Server 1`?

Comment: I'd create yourself a loopback linked server to fix the immediate need, and then go through and retroactively fix all of the procedures to remove the 4 piece convention (and maybe add local database synonyms in case you want to move them apart again, so that you can just update the synonym references in the future)

Comment: Consider using synonyms for cross-db or cross server references. Proc code could then reference synonyms that resolve to 3 or 4 part names.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky, no, after migration, Server 1 will be abandoned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that, post migration, you have *absolutely* no other need for this Linked Server to `Server 1`, then you should be able to drop and recreate it with the same name but pointing to the current / local instance (i.e. `Server 2`). This is known as a "loop back" and will allow the code to continue working unmodified.

HOWEVER, that is a short-term solution as you don't want to go through a Linked Server if you don't need to. You should go through all of the code and remove the `[Server1].` references. This loop back Linked Server is just a means of buying time to do these changes slowly rather than needing to have it all done up front.

Comment: You can run into problems trying to use a Loopback server in a transaction - you can get the dreaded 'Transaction context in use by another session.' error - See the section on Loopback servers here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188716.aspx

Comment: Thank you guys for the nice advise, I think I'll go through all code to remove the [Server1] references.